# Are there good spirits/benevolent spirits in Hinduism apart from ancestors?

Tags: scripture

Are there protective, benevolent spirits who appear to human beings apart from one's ancestors?

Comment: Gandharvas, Vidyadharas & Apsaras are benevolent spirits. Yakshas have both benevolent & malevolent nature.

Comment: Can Gandharvas and Vidyadharas appear to humans in spirit form though?

Comment: what do you mean by spirits??

Comment: Benevolent beings with a physical form who can come to protect humans or aid them